# Unexpected output in R with modulus operator

Tags: r, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, modulus, arithmetic-expressions

```
((10*(7655.7-7652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 16

((10*(655.7-652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 17

((10*(7655.7-7652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 16

((10*(8655.7-8652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 17

((10*(9655.7-9652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 17

((10*(7655.7-7652.3))%/%(2))
[1] 16
```

`%/%` operator gives the quotient so why is the result different when we replace the 9 in 9652.3 with 7 ?

Comment: there's an explanation there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: It is not a problem of modulus. If you type `(7655.7-7652.3)-(655.7-652.3)`, you get `-4.547474e-13` not 0. I think it is due to how R "stores" those numbers.